# Swift 3 : Decimal to Int

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdecimalnumber

I tried to convert Decimal to Int with the follow code:

```
Int(pow(Decimal(size), 2) - 1)
```

But I get:

```
.swift:254:43: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Decimal)'
```

Here I  know pow is returning a `Decimal` but it seems that Int has no constructors and member functions to convert `Decimal` to `Int`.
How can I convert Decimal to Int in Swift 3?

Comment: Use Decimal only for currency values. Except that use double or float.

Comment: `NSDecimalNumber(decimal: yourDecimal).intValue` should work.

Comment: Why did you say `Decimal(size)` to begin with?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is my updated answer (thanks to Martin R and the OP for the remarks). The OP's problem was just casting the `pow(x: Decimal,y: Int) -> Decimal` function to an Int after subtracting 1 from the result. I have answered the question with the help of this [SO post for NSDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548596/how-to-cast-an-nsdecimal-value-into-an-nsinteger-value) and [Apple's documentation on Decimal](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/decimal). You have to convert your result to an NSDecimalNumber, which can in turn be casted into an Int:

```
let size = Decimal(2)
let test = pow(size, 2) - 1
let result = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: test)
print(Int(result)) // testing the cast to Int
```

Comment: I just wanted to know how to convert Decimal to Int, unfortunately you misunderstood my goal.

Comment: There *is* a `pow(_ x: Decimal, _ y: Int) -> Decimal` function.

Answer (score 27):

```
let decimalToInt = (yourDecimal as NSDecimalNumber).intValue
```

or as @MartinR suggested:

```
let decimalToInt = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: yourDecimal).intValue
```

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks!

Comment: This can fail sometimes...  ```(lldb) po NSDecimalNumber(decimal: self)
10.6666666666666666666666666666666666666

(lldb) po NSDecimalNumber(decimal: self).intValue
0```. I think there is more of a discussion on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036637/nsdecimalnumberx-intvalue-returns-2-0-15-and-199-depending-on-the-amount-o), I think @Martin was pointing it out [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2980)

Comment: @ScottyBlades you are welcome to edit the answer with that fix

Comment: This is answer is dangerously incorrect. Here's an example:
`(lldb) po (Decimal(1201.68) as NSDecimalNumber).intValue
-642`

Answer (score 14):

If you have a very long decimal, then beware of rounding errors

```
let decimal = Decimal(floatLiteral: 100.123456)
let intValue = (decimal as NSDecimalNumber).intValue // This is 100
```

However

```
let veryLargeDecimal = Decimal(floatLiteral: 100.123456789123)
let intValue = (veryLargeDecimal as NSDecimalNumber).intValue // This is -84 !
```

I ensured I rounded my Decimal before I converted it to an Int, using `NSDecimalRound` (which you can put in an extension of Decimal).

```
var veryLargeDecimal = Decimal(floatLiteral: 100.123456789123)
var rounded = Decimal()
NSDecimalRound(&rounded, &veryLargeDecimal, 0, .down)
let intValue = (rounded as NSDecimalNumber).intValue // This is now 100
```

Comment: Absolutely right, thank you! Maybe `let veryLargeDecimal = Decimal(floatLiteral: 100.123456789123)
let intValue = Int((veryLargeDecimal as NSDecimalNumber).doubleValue)` would be shorter? .doubleValue seems to work properly.

Comment: There are people who go beyond apparent solutions and save lives :D

Comment: Be careful!!! This would not work for negative values `-101`. Check the correct approach for getting the whole value of a decimal number as shown at this post [Getting the decimal part of a double in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010456/2303865)

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong with either of the posted answers, but I would like to offer up an extension that reduces the verbosity for scenarios where you need to use this frequently.

```
extension Decimal {
    var int: Int {
        return NSDecimalNumber(decimal: self).intValue
    }
}
```

To call it:

```
let powerDecimal = pow(2, 2) // Output is Decimal
let powerInt = powerDecimal.int // Output is now an Int
```

Comment: I love cute little extensions, but... there's no way to do this without passing through NS-prefixed Foundation classes?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is an intermittent failure using some of the methods provided.

`NSDecimalNumber(decimal: <num>).intValue` can produce unexpected results...

```
(lldb) po NSDecimalNumber(decimal: self)
10.6666666666666666666666666666666666666

(lldb) po NSDecimalNumber(decimal: self).intValue
0
```

I think there is more of a discussion on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036637/nsdecimalnumberx-intvalue-returns-2-0-15-and-199-depending-on-the-amount-o), and @Martin was pointing it out [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2980)

Instead of using the decimal value directly, I made a work around that converts the decimal to a whole number before converting the Decimal to an Int.

```
extension Decimal {

   func rounded(_ roundingMode: NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode = .down, scale: Int = 0) -> Self {
        var result = Self()
        var number = self
        NSDecimalRound(&result, &number, scale, roundingMode)
        return result
    }
    
    var whole: Self { rounded( self < 0 ? .up : .down) }
    
    var fraction: Self { self - whole }
    
    var int: Int {
        NSDecimalNumber(decimal: whole).intValue
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks familiar :) [Getting the decimal part of a double in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010456/2303865)

Comment: I think the most concise approach would be using `plain` rounding as the default value. I have also updated the original post to use `sign == .minus` instead of `self < 0`. Note also that using `Self` instead of `Decimal` won't make any difference in this case other than syntax considering that `Decimal` is a struct not a protocol.

Answer (score -3):

Just use the description of `Decimal`, `String` replacement the `NSDecimalNumber` to bridge it.

```
extension Decimal {
    var intVal: Int? {
        return Int(self.description)
    }
}
```